# audio suddenly stutters, whole system freezes

Tags: 22.04, xubuntu

I was listening to some music using Strawberry when all of a sudden the audio on my computer started stuttering and the whole system became unresponsive. I had to turn off the computer and turn it back on to get it to stop. The computer already has bad RAM as it used to randomly shut off I'm bringing this up because I think it might be a probable cause, but I'm unsure if I should worry about that.

Specs:

- Sony VAIO VPCEB35FX
- Toshiba MQ01ABD100V HDD
- Intel Centrino N Band 1000 Wireless Card
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- Intel Core i3 CPU
- Xubuntu 22.04